# Why does my custom equals method (doubles and integers) not work?

Tags: java, equals

I have a custom equals to check the equality of my object called Pair.

```
class Pair implements Comparable <Parr> {

double coef;
int power;

Pair(double a, int b) {
    coef = a; 
    power = b; 
}
```

My custom equals method is (located in class pair):

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (!(o instanceof Pair))
        return false; 
    Pair that = (Pair) o; 
    return that.coef == this.coef && that.power == this.power; 
}
```

I've checked with print my object if the objects are the same, and they are indeed the same.

```
1.0 1 2.0 0
1.0 1 2.0 0
```

I call my custom equals from a different file, called Test.

```
class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    orig = pol1.differentiate().integrate();
    System.out.print(orig);
    if (orig.equals(pol1))
        System.out.println(" (is equal.)");
    else
    System.out.println(" (is not equal.)");
```

And my class Polynomial, which is an arraylist with objects of Pair inside.

```
class Polynominal implements PolynominalInterface {


ArrayList<Pair> terms = new ArrayList<Pair>();
```

I looked on the internet, and I found that I cannot use == in my Equals method, but I'm using Intergers and Doubles, so equals() would not work.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: We're going to have to see the `equals` and `hashCode` for `Polynomial`. The methods for `Parr` look fine (`==` is perfectly correct with primitive types) but I suspect the methods are wrong for `Polynomial`.

Comment: What is the type of `orig`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `orig` and `pol1` are instances of `Polynomial` then this

```
if (orig.equals(pol1))
```

would only work if you implement `Polynomial#equals()` as well; which would iterate the two `ArrayList`s and make sure individual `Pair`s are equal (using `Pair#equals()` of course).

Answer (score 2):

Ok, thanks to Ravi Thapliyal I found the solution.

After adding an custom equals method in my Polynominal class, the problem was fixed.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (!(o instanceof Polynomial))
        return false; 
    Polynomial that = (Polynomial) o; 
    return that.terms.equals(terms); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Double.compare(double, double)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#compare%28double,%20double%29) method instead of ==.

Floating point comparison is "fuzzy" in Java.

Comment: Thanks. You mean in this situation: Double.compare(that.coef, this.coef) ? 

This unfortunately will not work because of the && and the Double.compare returns an integer. Or am I misinterpreting your comment?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to implement a Polynomail.equals() method something like the following:

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
  if (!(o instanceof Polynomial)) return false;

  Polynomial other = (Polynomial) o;

  if (this.terms==null && other.terms==null) return true;

  // A suitable equals() method already exists for ArrayList, so we can use that
  // this will in turn use Pair.equals() which looks OK to me
  if (this.terms!=null && other.terms!=null) return this.terms.equals(other.terms);

  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two issues come to mind: the first is that the default `hashCode()` method will seldom return the same value for any two distinct object instances, regardless of their contents.  This is a good thing if the `equals()` method will never report two distinct object instances as equal, but is a bad thing if it will.  *Every* object which overrides `Object.equals()` should also override `Object.hashCode()` so that if `x.equals(y)`, then `x.hashCode()==y.hashCode()`; this is important because even non-hashed generic collections may use objects' hash codes to expedite comparisons.  *If you don't want to write a "real" hash function, simply pick some arbitrary integer and have your type's `hashCode()` method always return that*.  Any hashed collection into which your type is stored will perform slowly, but all collections into which it is stored should behave correctly.

The second issue you may be seeing is that floating-point comparisons are sometimes dodgy.  Two numbers may be essentially equal but compare unequal.  Worse, the IEEE decided for whatever reason that floating-point "not-a-number" values should compare unequal to everything--*even themselves*.

Factoring both of these issues together, I would suggest that you might want to rewrite your `equals` method to chain to the `equals` method of `double`.  Further, if neither field of your object will be modified while it's stored in a collection, have your `hashCode()` method compute the `hashCode` of the `int`, multiply it by some large odd number, and then add or xor that with the `hashCode` of the `double`.  If your object might be modified while stored in a collection, have `hashCode()` return a constant.  If you don't override `hashCode()` you cannot expect the `equals` methods of any objects which contain yours to work correctly.